# E.F. lambda expression for a List<string> with StartsWith

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, lambda

I'm developing an Entity Framework 6.1.2 library with .NET Framework 4.5.1 and C#.

I have this predicate:

```
Expression<Func<EXTERNAL_CODES, bool>> predicate = null;
List<string> codes = GetStartEntCodes(startingCode, quantity);

predicate = (e =>
        e.USED == 0
    && codes.Contains(e.CODE)
    && e.CHINA_CODES_HEADER_ID == batch.Id
    && e.CODE_LEVEL == codeLevel
    && (e.BATCH_ID == batch.Id || e.BATCH_ID == null));
```

But this part `&& chinaCodes.Contains(e.CODE)` doesn't work.

`e.CODE` is nvarchar(20) and each string on `codes` list contains only the first 15 characters.

I want to do this:

```
`WHERE CODE LIKE `codes.value%'; -- Note: `codes.value%' represents each value in codes list.`
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like that:

```
        predicate = (e =>
                e.USED == 0
            && codes.Any(x => x.StartsWith(e.CODE))
            && e.CHINA_CODES_HEADER_ID == batch.Id
            && e.CODE_LEVEL == codeLevel
            && (e.BATCH_ID == batch.Id || e.BATCH_ID == null));
```

Comment: A `.Where()` would return the list of matching values, which would not work as this is a boolean evaluation. Changing it to `.Any()` with the exact same predicate should fix that.

Comment: According to MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738550(v=vs.110).aspx) `StartsWith` is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

```
chinaCodes.Contains(e.CODE)
```

You have to make a distinction between `String.Contains()` and `IEnumerable<T>.Contains()`.

On a string, the method will return whether *some part of the string* contains your given parameter. (Which is what you want)

On a collection, the method will return whether the collections *contains an element that is exactly alike* (not just part of it!).

You need to check if **(1) your code starts with** **(2) any of the codes in the list**.

This is the correct LINQ statement for that:

```
chinaCodes.Any(x => e.CODE.StartsWith(x) )
```

**Edit** I misinterpreted your question originally, but have already corrected my answer.